# SQLite query to match text string in column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database column that contains text in CSV format. A sample cell looks like this:

```
Audi,Ford,Chevy,BMW,Toyota
```

I'd like to generate a query that matches any column with the string 'BMW'. How can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use wildcard characters: `%`

```
select * from table 
where name like '%BMW%'
```

Comment: if i want to pull 'audi' & 'BMW' , how can i do that ?

Comment: It would be: `select * from table where name like '%BMW%' or name like '%audi%'`

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Column LIKE '%BMW%'
```

the % are wildcards for the LIKE statement.

More information can be found [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where name like '%BMW%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Way...

```
--Create Table 2 :
Create Table #Table1
(
    Roll_No INT, 
    Student_Address Varchar(200)
)
Go

-- Insert Values into #Table1: 
Insert into #Table1 Values ('1','1st Street')
Insert into #Table1 Values ('2','2rd Street')
Insert into #Table1 Values ('3','3rd Street')
Insert into #Table1 Values ('4','4th Road')
Insert into #Table1 Values ('5','5th Street')
Insert into #Table1 Values ('6','6th Street')
Insert into #Table1 Values ('7','7th Street')
Insert into #Table1 Values ('8','8th Wing')

--Query
Select * from #Table1 where CharIndex('Street',Student_Address) > 0

--Clean Up:
Drop table #Table1
```